# How to access a Class from one form to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, syntax-error

I'm trying to get the public class pet to wear in different forms as a connection but I can not do, where can I put the public class pet to make connection with each forms that I create ??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace prueba
{
   static class Program
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// Punto de entrada principal para la aplicación.
    /// </summary>  

        public class mascotas
        {
            public string nombremascota, nombredueño, sexo, especie, estado, respuesta;
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
     }
  }
```

I try to make connection with this form but i have a error in mascotas <--

```
this.listnombresmas.Items.Add(((mascotas)capturar[i]).);
```

the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace prueba
{
    public partial class verdatos : Form
    {
        ArrayList capturar = new ArrayList();

        public verdatos(ArrayList mascotaguardar)
        {
            capturar = mascotaguardar;
            InitializeComponent();
            cargadatos();
        }
       void cargadatos()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < capturar.Count; i++)
            {
                this.listnombresmas.Items.Add(((mascotas)capturar[i]).);
            }
        }
        private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

the other form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace prueba
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class mascotas
        {
            public string nombremascota, nombredueño, sexo, especie, estado, respuesta;
        }

        string especie = "Pajaro", sexo = "Hembra", respuesta = "Si";
        ArrayList nuevamascota = new ArrayList();

        //----------------No Modificar NADA-------------------
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(compruebadatos()==true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Guardado con éxito");
                almacenadatos();
                resetcontrols();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Faltan datos");
            }
        }
        void resetcontrols()
        {
            this.tnomdueño.Text = "";
            this.tnommascota.Text = "";
            this.radiopajaro.Checked = true;
            this.radiohembra.Checked = true;
            this.radiosi.Checked = true;
            this.listvivienda.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        void almacenadatos()
        {
            mascotas almacenar = new mascotas();
            almacenar.nombremascota = this.tnommascota.Text;
            almacenar.nombredueño = this.tnomdueño.Text;
            almacenar.estado = this.listvivienda.Text;
            almacenar.especie = especie;
            almacenar.respuesta = respuesta;
            almacenar.sexo = sexo;

            nuevamascota.Add(almacenar);
        }

        #region botones

        private void radiopajaro_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(radiopajaro.Checked)
            {
                especie = "Pajaro";
            }
        }

        private void radioperro_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(radioperro.Checked)
            {
                especie = "Perro";
            }
        }

        private void radiogato_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(radiogato.Checked)
            {
                especie = "Gato";
            }
        }

        private void radioconejo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(radioconejo.Checked)
            {
                especie = "Conejo";
            }
        }

        private void radioerizo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(radioerizo.Checked)
            {
                especie = "Erizo";
            }
        }

        #endregion

        bool compruebadatos()
        {
            if(tnommascota.Text == "" || tnomdueño.Text == "")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        private void buttonverdatos2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: mascostas is a class nested in Program and in Form1. First I'd remove one of them then use full name to identify it (for example Form1.mascotas or Program.mascotas, according to which one you'll keep and which one you'll drop). Even better (in your case) drop one of them and move that class outside its containing class to make it directly accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project, "Add" and "Class...", type `mascotas.cs` for name and define your class. You will have something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class mascotas
    {
        public string nombremascota, nombredueño, sexo, especie, estado, respuesta;
    }
}
```

You defined `mascotas` as a nested class an thus you can not access to it from an another class.

If you mean this!